# Unexpected output when using PHP shell_exec with dpkg utility

Tags: php, shell

Running the following code:

```
$version = shell_exec('dpkg -l myprogram | grep myprogram');
```

The problem is, when the package doesn't exist on the system, `$version` is `NULL`. I expect to actually get "No packages found matching myprogram", which is what happens when I run the command on the command-line.

Code works fine when *myprogram* does exist.

Note, adding "2>&1" (which is a suggestion I saw on other similar questions) to the end of the command does not help.

Curious why I'm getting different results within PHP versus the command-line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably misplaced the `2>&1`. The right place to put it is before the pipe:

```
$version = shell_exec('dpkg -l myprogram 2>&1 | grep myprogram');
```

This works (just tested on a ubuntu) as expected: `dpkg` outputs to stderr the error message, with `2>&1` you redirect it to the stdout, which is then passed through grep, ending into the php variable as you need.

Comment: Ah, that does it. Thank you.